# positioning of divs when height set to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario while writing an html code.. that inbetween some floating divs... there comes two divs with absolute positioning.. and Ive created a sample jsfiddle to show the issue.. try entering a long text like for example "CSS overflow hidden with absolute position · how do I prevent ... Size of overflow:hidden div with position:absolute one inside · CSS/HTML ...".. and clickon submite button...it will get appended in the mainContainer... since the text is too long and that container div is set to auto..it will extend and go behind the textbox container div.. is there anyway I dould make the textbox container to move down according to the height needed for the main container to get visible area and then move back up if not needed.. im using the absolute positioning due to one factor..as when I add width:100% in css.. that div usually leaves a gap between left margin and the start of that div... and it appears as a blank space.. please check the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/EVwSG/5/

HTML
    
    Enter

CSS

```
#mainContainer{
width:50%;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:20px;
background-color:#000000;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:19px;
}


 #textboxContainer{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:green;
top:60px;
left:0;
}

#inputBox{
width:80%;
}​
```

​

Comment: To me, there is no problem (using Google Chrome)

Comment: it goes in befind the div ..right... add a long text like the one in my example..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with using position: absolute. If you remove this from both div elements and allow them to be block level elements it will allow everything to render as you'd expect. If you need these to be positioned absolutely I recommend creating a parent element whose position is relative so it does not appear behind the other div on the page.

You can calculate height like the other answers specify but I think it's best to leave that to the browser if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to grab the height of the new element and then add the top to it.

```
$("#textboxContainer").css("top", $("#mainContainer").height() + 20);
```

This will move the bottom container lower to the correct height. Here's a link to the [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EVwSG/10/).

Comment: this one wrks..let me try it in my website

Comment: if you enter blank text this will move the div higher than where it started